# how to filter a string without using any additional data structures(no additional strs, lists etc.) nor any string methods?

Tags: python-3.x, string, filter, palindrome

I am trying to make a function that checks whether or not a string is a palindrome. It should only consider alphanumeric chars, including no spaces. I basically have to code whats below without any methods on the string (so no isalnum(), lower() etc.), nor adding additional data structures(so without the y/' '). I cant think of a way to achieve this. Is it possible? The function should consider uppercase chars equal to their lower case counter partts

```
def isPalindrome_py(x):
    y = ''
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i] == ' ':
            pass
        elif x[i].isalnum():
            y += x[i]
    y = y.lower()
    if y[::-1] == y:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

edit:
as an example - isPalindrome_py("#RaCe CaR$!") should return True

Comment: Why cannot use any string method - like `isalnum()` - that's Python built-ins?

Comment: This is the constraint

Answer (score 0):

```
def isPal(x):
    if len(x) < 2:
        return True
    elif not ('0' <= x[0] <= '9' or 'A' <= x[0] <= 'Z' or 'a' <= x[0] <= 'z'):
        return isPal(x[1:])
    elif not ('0' <= x[-1] <= '9' or 'A' <= x[-1] <= 'Z' or 'a' <= x[-1] <= 'z'):
        return isPal(x[:-1])
    elif x[0] != x[-1] and x[0] >= 'A' and x[-1] >= 'A' and ord(x[0]) + 32 != ord(x[-1]) and ord(x[0]) - 32 != ord(x[-1]):
        return False
    else:
        return isPal(x[1:-1])
```

Now let's unpack this monster

This function works by trying to find characters that would imply that the string is not a palindrome, and if it can't find any violations, concluding that the string must be a palindrome.

The first clause checks if the string is trivially a palindrome (since single characters and the empty string are all palindromes)

The second clause (`elif not ('0' <= x[0]`...) checks if the first character in the string is alphanumeric. If it isn't it's disregarded.

The third clause does the same but for the last character in the string.

The fourth clause checks whether the first character in the string is the same as the last character in the string. It makes use of the fact that uppercase and lowercase letters are 32 removed from each other in ASCII.